# How to test transaction log shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-backups, transaction-log, disaster-recovery

We are a small division of a larger company and we are required to keep a server at the corporate office as a disaster recovery server.  I want to use SQL's (2005) transaction log shipping feature to keep the offsite server up-to-date.

The problem is that Mama Corprorate wants proof that the database is functional.  For example, a screenshot of the remote session showing a query of the orders table showing the most recent group of orders (with the order date).  Is there a way to satisfy this requirement without breaking the log shipping?  I suggested that I give them a screen of the history for the LS Restore job, but they didn't like that idea since "that really isn't telling you that its working" according to them.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `Jes Schultz Borland`'s demos: [Log Shipping Part 1: Preparing for Disaster](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/log-shipping-preparing-for-disaster/), [Log Shipping Part 2: When Disaster Strikes](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/03/log-shipping-part-2-when-disaster-strikes-video/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the videos above from Bogdan Sahlean, I changed the database mode from NORECOVERY TO STANDBY and that has resolved the issue.  This allows us to still run the same query as evidence.